# ASC time index in timescaleDB

Tags: postgresql, indexing, timescaledb

I'm building a TimescaleDB local server and I'm creating my first "production" hypertables. The point is that, at the moment, all the future consumers of my DB are going to use the data in `ASC` order, but by default timescale creates a `DESC` index in the time column.

My doubt is, does it worth to change the default behaviour and make the index to be `ASC`?

I don't know if it's `DESC` by default for a good reason and I'm going to have some penalty. I have also read that indexs in postgresql can be read backward, so a `DESC` index could be used in an `ASC` query, but I don't know if there are performance penalties.

In the other hand, it's safe to simple delete the default index and create a new one with different order? Also not sure if deleting it I'm going to screw up some timescale internal functionality.

Thanks for your time,

H25E

Comment: I think it's safe to drop the index but I'd double-check if it's being used. You can create the reverse index, check if you get any performance improvement, and drop the other later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single-column index, it does not matter at all if it is created `ASC` or `DESC`, because indexes can be read in both directions with the same efficiency.

The only time when you really need to specify `DESC` in an index is if the index is supposed to support an `ORDER BY` clause like `ORDER BY a, b DESC`. Then one of the index columns must be sorted `ASC` and the other `DESC` — but again it doesn't matter which one is `ASC` and which `DESC`, as the index can be read in both directions.

So, for a single column index, there is no need to build the index again, and there was no good reason to create it `DESC` in the first place (but it doesn't matter).